# angular directive toggling a class

Tags: angularjs

I've got the following code where i'm attempting to toggle the first occurrence of a class. The problem is it's not working, and I have no idea as to why not.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('someApp')

.directive('eventButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            eventItemDisplayed: '@'
        },
        transclude: true,
        replace: false,
        template: '<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleEvent()">{{text}}</button>',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.eventItemDisplayed = false;
            $scope.text = 'Show'
            $scope.toggleEvent = function () {
                element.find('event-details:first').toggleClass('hide-event');
                $scope.eventItemDisplayed = ($scope.eventItemDisplayed) ? false : true;
                if ($scope.eventItemDisplayed) {
                    $scope.text = 'Show';
                } else {
                    $scope.text = 'Hide';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
})();
```

The HTML looks as follows:

```
<event-button></event-button>
<div class="event-details hide-event">
```

If I use

```
element.next().toggleClass('hide-element')
```

Then it works fine i.e. it adds the class to the element as expected. I suspect that's because next() returns an element whereas find() is returning a selector representing a class?

Comment: What is the goal here? I am asking because it looks like what you want is ng-class, not a custom directive.

Comment: I have an unordered list with variable items broken up into sections. Only one section needs to have a class toggled. There is a button at the top of the block of sections for each item. When the button is clicked it applies a class to the middle section.

Comment: It's because of `element.find()` finds an elements inside `element` (i.e. `<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleEvent()">{{text}}</button>`). So it's failure because there is no  nested element with class `.event-details`. Oh! wait! You're trying to find a TAG `event-details`, but not a CLASS `.event-details`

Comment: Thanks Max, I tried both ('.event-details') and ('event-details) - neither worked. You're first observation was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since class `event-details` doesnt lie inside(is not in its children) the directive element you cant find it with find()

Next works as it is next sibling of the directive element

the  `element.next()` will take you to you  `<div class="event-details hide-event">`  as it is next sibling of `<event-button></event-button>`

Comment: my pleasure, you can accept it as an answer if t helped you :)